# AWS lambda edge for external auth

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am setting up lambda at edge with the steps listed in this below link. I created lambda function and updated code given in the link. I want to test the function before deploying as edge function. So in lambda console tried to test it but ending with below error. Please assist.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/external-server-authorization-with-lambdaedge/

START RequestId: 9fd80897-38b9-423b-9274-33738245d8a1 Version: $LATEST
2024-03-05T17:51:22.077Z    9fd80897-38b9-423b-9274-33738245d8a1    ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')","    at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:21:29)","    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1173:29)"]}
END RequestId: 9fd80897-38b9-423b-9274-33738245d8a1
REPORT RequestId: 9fd80897-38b9-423b-9274-33738245d8a1  Duration: 31.10 ms  Billed Duration: 32 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 67 MB  Init Duration: 210.06 ms

I created lambda function and updated code given in the link. I want to test the function before deploying as edge function. So in lambda console tried to test it but ending with below error. Please assist.